# How to make a dropdown enabled on change event using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

My form consists of a checkbox and a dropdown in the header and several dropdowns in the main content of my page. On page-load, I want all of the dropdowns to be disabled. Once the checkbox is checked, I want the header dropdown enabled. If the user chooses an option in the header dropdown, all of the other dropdowns should become selectable. Finally, if the checkbox in the header is clicked again, all of the dropdowns should be disabled again.

Here is the code I have tried:

**HTML**:

```
Header:
<br /><input type="checkbox" name="approve" />
<select id="myddl" name="myddl">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Twooo</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<div class="detail">
    <p>Detail</p>
        <br />
    <select id="Select1" name="myddl"  >
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="Select2" name="myddl"  >
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="Select3" name="myddl"  >
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="Select4" name="myddl"  >
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
<br />
    <select id="Select5" name="myddl" >
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
 $('.detail').find('select').attr("disabled"); 

$("#myddl").change(function()
{  $('.detail').find('select').removeAttr("disabled"); 
     $('.detail').find('select').val($(this).val());

});
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/8SpTk/5/)**

Comment: You really need to think your question through thoroughly before posting. You changed what you were wanting several times. Also for the sake of those in the future, please post your code here as well just in case jsfiddle isnt available.

Comment: are you the one who vote down? not several time just one time and you can have a look at my question history

Comment: the reason i ask you about down vote is to know the reason for that.... and yes i forgot to write you the change request i made... i will up vote your answer too :)

Comment: Tell you the truth, it was really annoying, you changed the question two times, didn't show any effort of solving it by your own. I felt like I'm being abused. :(

Comment: sorry gdoron/josh yes it was my mistake thank you guys for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var drops = $('.detail select');
var $header = $('#myddl');
$('input[name="approve"]').change(function() {
    $header.prop('disabled', !this.checked);

    if (!this.checked) {
        drops.prop('disabled', true);
    }
});

drops.add($header).prop('disabled', true);

$header.change(function() {
    drops.prop('disabled', false);
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/8SpTk/18/)

Note that this code cache the `select` elements thus it doesn't need to query the dom multiple times.

Comment: you guys are fast, i have updated my question and some how i missed what i was pasting, please have a look, sorry

Comment: thanks but when i unceck the checkbox it should disabled back again... almost there :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
var $ddls = $('select');
var $check = $('#check');
var $ddlHeader = $("#myddl");
var $ddlDetails = $('.detail select');

$ddls.prop("disabled", true); 

$check.click(function() {
    $ddls.prop("disabled", true); 
    $ddlHeader.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});

$ddlHeader.change(function() {  
    $ddlDetails.removeAttr("disabled"); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8SpTk/23/)

Comment: you guys are fast, i have updated my question and some how i missed what i was pasting, please have a look, sorry

Comment: **1.** Use your native DOM properties when you can. **2.** Don't query the DOM multiple times if you don't have to. **3.** `this` is the DOM element that the event was attached to.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I usually reuse selectors in my code. I guess I was just being lazy. :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure if this it's what you want to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/8SpTk/10/

```
$('.detail select').attr('disabled', true);

$("#myddl").change(function()
{  
    $('.detail select').attr('disabled', false).val($(this).val());
});
```